# Difference between busboy and connect-busboy

Tags: node.js

On [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy)'s page, I see this description: *Connect middleware for busboy*, but this doesn't tell me anything (being new to node.js).

What is the difference between [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) and [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy)? I am trying to find out if the second one is different from the first one or they are complementary. I can't understand from their examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) is a middleware layer for building servers in Node.js. It was originally the basis for the [Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) web framework.

What middleware here really means is essentially an array of [functions](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#use-middleware) that conform to an interface which get called on each request in the order they are defined.

[connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy) wraps the [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) library into a connect compatible middleware. You can see in the source it really just returns a function.

If you're using express you might want to take a look at [express-busboy](https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy) which uses [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) under the hood and has recent updates.